On the identity $\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \leq \frac{x}{n}} \frac{\mu(k)}{k}=1$

For all $x\geq 2$
$$
\sum_{n \leq x} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \leq \frac{x}{n}} \frac{\mu(k)}{k}=1.
$$

This is an exercise in The Development of Prime Number Theory:
From Euclid to Hardy and Littlewood by Władysław Narkiewicz. There is a source given:
Gram,J.P. (1884): Undersøgesler angaaende Maengden af Primtal under en given
Graense. K.Danske Vidensk. Selskabs Skrifter, Nat.Math.Afd., 6, 183-308.
I searched trough every page but I could not find the statement. So I wanted to prove it by myself but I do not think that any Möbius Inversion formula can help here. I know that for all $x\geq 1$
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} \mu(n)\left\lfloor\frac{x}{n}\right\rfloor=1
$$
but this does not help a lot. Any ideas?

Writing $m=nk$,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \le x} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k \le x/n} \frac{\mu(k)}{k} &= \sum_{nk\le x} \frac1{nk} \mu(k) = \sum_{m\le x} \frac1m \sum_{k\mid m} \mu(k) = \sum_{m\le x} \frac1m {\mathbb1}[m=1] = \frac11 = 1.
\end{align*}

Is $1[m=1]$ the indicator function?
